# What Is Wrong With This ? I Can't Click On The Link

Tags: html

```
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>Stackoverflow</li>

  <li><a href="#Sixth"></a>Go To Sixth Article</li>
```

I already Have An Article With id = Sixth and the another 5 articles work fine

Comment: The text needs to go **inside** the link; otherwise there is nothing to click on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You link titles must be placed between the start and closing tags

```
<li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a></li>

<li><a href="#Sixth">Go To Sixth Article</a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to put **text** inside **anchor tags** `<a>...</a>`,
here's how your code will look like

```html
<li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a></li>
<li><a href="#Sixth">Go To Sixth Article</a></li>
```

Live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/ue7ym3n8/